# BigChainDb: testnet.bigchaindb.com with MongoDb?

Tags: node.js, bigchaindb

So why I am following this example:

https://github.com/manolodewiner/query-mongodb-bigchaindb/blob/master/queryMongo.js

but I am using a testnet server provided by bigChainDb, so I am doing this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


const urlMongo = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

const dbName = 'bigchain'




let conn = new driver.Connection('https://test.bigchaindb.com/api/v1/', { 
    app_id: 'yyyyyy',
    app_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
})

const alice = new driver.Ed25519Keypair();
const bob = new driver.Ed25519Keypair();

const assetdata = {
    'invoice': {
            'invoiceNo': '811',
            'issuedBy': 'supplier1',
    }

}
```

Which apparently is wrong because according to documentation here:

> How to Connect to MongoDB Before you can query a MongoDB database, you
>   must connect to it, and to do that, you need to know its hostname and
>   port.
>
> If you’re running a BigchainDB node on your local machine (e.g. for
>   dev and test), then the hostname should be localhost and the port
>   should be 27017, unless you did something to change those values. If
>   you’re running a BigchainDB node on a remote machine and you can SSH
>   to that machine, then the same is true.
>
> If you’re running a BigchainDB node on a remote machine and you
>   configured its MongoDB to use auth and to be publicly-accessible (to
>   people with authorization), then you can probably figure out its
>   hostname and port.

https://docs.bigchaindb.com/en/latest/query.html

In the example code, manolodewiner is 'pairing' his local bigchaindb with the local mongodb, which is the default setup, right?

But in my current code, I am obviously pointing to my local mongodb but the bigchain is remote, on the bigchain's test network, but this is not working-   nothing is being written on my local mongodb and no mongo query is working, what should I do in order to "pair" the remote test.bigchaindb with my local mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current BigchainDB Testnet (at test.bigchaindb.com) doesn't allow external users to connect directly to the MongoDB instances in its nodes. Nor can you start up a local node and add it to the BigchainDB Testnet. It's a "permissioned network": existing network nodes must explicitly add your node to the network.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The TestNet exposes the HTTP API and the WebSocket events API.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm not getting what the point is.
I want to do proof-of-concept, but if I can't verify that the data persists "on the network", even though my server "crashes", then I'm not checking for anything more than a simple traditional mongoDB query.